# How to configure local web server such that it should switch between one php version to another

Tags: php, apache, centos, lampp

I'm developing one web application, using PHP eclipse IDE.
For an instance i want to switch from one PHP version to another version which resides in different location.

**Below is my working environment :**

1) Having Centos OS

2) PHP 5.1.6 have installed already while installing centos OS

3) Above PHP is installed in /usr/bin/ path

4) I have installed LAMPP in /opt/lampp

5) In LAMPP present PHP 5.2.6 version

I want to configure local web server such that lampp should choose PHP 5.1.6 (which resides in /opt/lampp )
I am not aware of this switching of PHP version.

Please suggest me how should i configure this switching of PHP version in my local web server.
Which configuration file should i choose for modifying this change.

Thanks a lot !!!

-Pravin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/

This guide is a great guide and will get you started!

Another alternative would be to install Xampp, as I believe they provide a batch file that helps you switch versions of PHP in a second.

Comment: Thanks RobertPitt, I referred above link, bt it's related to windows..can you provide Centos OS related link if u have..that will be more useful for me...thanks

Comment: your best bet is to analyze the source files of Xammp PHP Switch and find out what is being changed, and then just reflect on Cent OS